# MySQL query, finding from one table and insert into second table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am looking for the following:

[image]

- Need the row with this condition: Common values of Device columns  AND first three chars of Interface column from both tables.
- Then the row which matched the above condition from Table1, retrieve the value of Specified column and store it in the Avgin column of the Table2 in the row where above condition matched.

Can someone help me with it? Database is MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are more than one matches, only the first one will be used.
If there are none, null will be used. If you would like something else, use `ifnull()`.

```
UPDATE
  table2
SET
  avgin=ifnull(
    (
      SELECT
        Specified
      FROM
        table1
      WHERE
        table1.Device=table2.Device
        AND substring(table1.Interface,1,3)=substring(table2.Interface,1,3)
      LIMIT 1
    ),
    'default value'
  )
```

**edit**: added the `ifnull()`

Comment: Hi, Thanks! It worked, but how & where should I use ifnull()? I am new to MySQL.

Comment: Is there no way by which I can set two as correct answers??? You and Mahmoud Gamal both are right..

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` with `JOIN` is what you need here, something like this:

```
UPDATE Table2 AS t2
INNER JOIN table1 AS t1  ON LEFT(t2.Interface, 3) = LEFT(t1.Interface, 3)
                        AND t1.Device             = t2.Device
SET t2.Avgin = t1.specified;
```

With the `JOIN` condition, as you explained in your question:

```
 LEFT(t2.Interface, 3) = LEFT(t1.Interface, 3)
 AND 
 t1.Device             = t2.Device
```

[`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_left) will give you the first 3 chars from the left of both table.

See it in action here:

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0db8c/1)

This will make the `table2` looks like:

```
|         CID |       DEVICE | INTERFACE |  AVGIN |
---------------------------------------------------
| HDC-HKG-R01 | HDC-TBONE-P1 |   P09/0/0 | 121.36 |
| OCB-OCD-R01 |      OCB-PE1 |     Gi5/2 |   0.17 |
| HDC-BSA-R01 | HDC-TBONE-P1 |   Se9/2/0 | (null) |
```

Comment: Is there no way by which I can set two as correct answers??? You and nl-x both are right..

Comment: @Sanchit don't think so. which solution are you actually going to use? the one with the inner join or the one with the subquery? (Otherwise, which solution was first?)

Comment: @Sanchit Its al right, it doesn't matter whose got the accepted, but I think the answer nl-x answer is better and he was faster than me.

Comment: So nice of you Mahmoud Gamal :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this to confirm you're getting the rows you're expecting (ie *BEFORE* updating anything):

```
SELECT
  t1.Specified

FROM
  table2 t2

  INNER JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.device = t2.device
  AND LEFT(t1.interface,3) = LEFT(t2.interface,3)
```

And then, assuming that's right:

```
  UPDATE table2 t2

  INNER JOIN table1 t1
  ON t1.device = t2.device
  AND LEFT(t1.interface,3) = LEFT(t2.interface,3)

  SET t2.Avgin = ifnull(t1.specified,'Default Value For When t1.Specified is NULL')
```

Note we're using an INNER join... that means that rows from table2 that have no corresponding row in table1, are discarded from the results (which is what you want).

The `IFNULL` will allow you to use a default value in the case when your join succeeds (because `device` and first three chars of `interface` are common to both tables), but `table1.specified` has a NULL value for that row.

Comment: Mahmoud Gamal's solution worked as I wanted. Thanks Anyways :)

Comment: @Sanchit Updated this answer with IFNULL too, in case you're interested in this syntax.

Comment: @Sepster your current `ifnull()` implementation won't work, because you are using an `INNER JOIN`, leaving the not-corresponding rows out of scope. you can TRY using `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @nl-x Incorrect... The column `specified` can be NULL, when the INNER JOIN on `device` and `interface` succeeds. ie this way, `table2.avgin` is left null when no match exists in `table1`, or updated to whatever column `t1.specified` contains if that column is not null, or is updated to whatever default is hard-coded when the `table1.specified` is NULL. Comes down to what OP actually wanted... his comment "but how & where should I use ifnull()" was hardly a detailed requirements spec ;-), but I believe this answer covers all bases.